# Reapply AngularJS after changing HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Inside a larger legacy app I have a view that uses AngularJS. In this view, I use a directive to display a Bootstrap modal (its content is created on the backend, then appended to the DOM).

No AngularJS methods seem to be working inside the modal. I understand it's because the modal content is appended to the DOM *after* AngularJS has compiled.

I'm looking for a way to allow the use AngularJS braces and methods inside the modal template. I've tried looking into `$compile`, `$apply`, and `$digest`, but so far I haven't been able to get it to work.

Relevant part of the code:

```js
    myApp.directive('formModal', ['$http', function($http) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: true,
            replace: true,
            template: '...',
            link: function postLink(scope){
                // ...
                $http({url: url}).then(function (response) {
                    if (response.data.status) {
                        modal.show({
                            title: 'Modal title',
                                content: response.data.form_html,
                                onShow: function ($modal) {
                                    // ...
                                }
                            });
                        };
                    })
                };
            }
        };
    }]);
```

And part of the template where the modal is opened:

```html
<form-modal class="btn-success" id="btn-form">
</form-modal>
```

Comment: Your understanding is correct. A modal has been appended to the DOM completely "outside of Angular's world", so Angular has no idea about this modal and doesn't work in it. This legacy app you are maintaining looks like a dirty mix of AngularJS and jQuery/vanilla JS, it must be full of hacks. I've forgotten everything about AngularJS though, so I'm unable to help :( Sorry

Comment: One option would be to add the https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ bundle and use $uibmodal...